# I need to put the scrollbar of pre tag in the line of the content

Tags: php, html

I have text files, with thousand of lines, and I want to make a php page where I can see them, and that it opens in the exact line where I want. I mean, the scrollbar must be in the line I want. The file is full open on a pre Tag, but the scroll bar must be in the line 'N'.

This the php to open the file:

```
 echo "<pre >";
 $file = $pathOfFile;
 $contents = file_get_contents($file);
 $lines = explode("<br>", $contents); // this is your array of words

 foreach($lines as $word)
        echo $word; 

 echo"</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to prepend each entry with an anchor tag:

```
echo '<pr>';
$file = $pathOfFile;
$contents = $file_get_contents($file);
$lines = explode('<br>', $contents);

$i = 0;
foreach($lines as $word)
{
    echo '<a name="' . $i . '"></a>' . $word . '<br>';
    ++$i;
}

echo '</pre>';
```

So your end html would like this:

```
<pre>
    <a name="0"></a>Line 1<br>
    <a name="1"></a>Line 2<br>
    <a name="2"></a>Line 3</br>
    ...
    <a name="500"></a>Line 500
</pre>
```

Then when you load the page, and want to scroll to a specific tag, use an anchor in the URL. For instance, if you want to go to line 500 of 700, go to:

http://yoursite.com/somepage.php#500